# import csv file to mysql database using python3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, xampp

I am trying to upload a CSV file to MySQL database using python3 the following error occurred.

ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'acc-Part8.csv into table 12_September_2019_2052 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSE' at line 1

by using python2.7 my problem is solved. I didn't get any error, the file is uploaded to the database.

here i am sorting the csv files based on date creation

```
lst_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
lst_files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
nf = "\n".join(lst_files)
k = len(lst_files)
z = lst_files[k-1]
a= (datetime.datetime.now())
a = str(a.strftime("%d_%B_%Y_%H%M"))
Table_name = str(a)
sqlLoadData = """load data local infile """+`z`+""" into table """+Table_name+""" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;"""
```

(python2.7)

this is the command I used for python2.7

if I use the same command with python3.5 (``) these quotes showing syntax error
so, I removed these quotes, I got the above error.

will anybody please resolve this problem

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this
where z = filename
l = "'"+z+"'"
sqlLoadData = """load data local infile """+l+""" into table """+Table_name+""" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;"""